# W3C Validation error: there is no attribute X

Tags: validation

I edit the post, and for many changes i have 1error :  there is no attribute X

> You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the
>   document type you are using does not support that attribute for this
>   element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict"
>   document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the
>   "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by
>   using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is
>   usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).
>
> This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in
>   the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no
>   supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error
>   message for further information.
>
> How to fix: check the spelling and case of the element and attribute,
>   (Remember XHTML is all lower-case) and/or check that they are both
>   allowed in the chosen document type, and/or use CSS instead of this
>   attribute. If you received this error when using the  element
>   to incorporate flash media in a Web page, see the FAQ item on valid
>   flash.
>
> ```
> Line 71, column 16: there is no attribute "property"
>
> <meta property='og:locale' content='en_US'/>
> ```

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advanced.

---

**1 Update:**
I replace the

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

with :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

The error didn't any more, but i have any other errors.

---

**2 update**

i replace in the header.php the

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en_US" />
```

to:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en_us" />
```

The second thing that i have done:
In the `opengraph.php` (Yoast  plugin) i replace the:

```
if ( $echo )
            echo "<meta property='og:locale' content='" . esc_attr( $locale ) . "'/>\n";
        else
            return $locale;
```

to:

```
if ( $echo )
            echo "<meta property='og:locale' content='en_us'/>\n";
        else
            return $locale;
```

But the result is the same. 1 error.

Answer (score 2):

The `<meta>` tag doesn't have an attribute called "property". You appear to be validating Open Graph protocol tags using the W3C's HTML validator. This is pretty much guaranteed not to work. It might be advantageous to look at [Facebook's debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). It should provide feedback on OG markup.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I validating Open Graph protocol and i didn't have any errors. which may be the problem?